# Element should remain opened on hover

Tags: jquery

I try to show an element X on `mouseenter` element Y and to hide it on `mouseleave` element Y.

So far it works OK.

In addition to that I would like element X after hovering over it, to stay opened.
After hovering out of element X, it should be hidden.

Can you please help me to find out where is problem in the code?
(I use jquery 1.3.2)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.kukuk').mouseenter(showBox).mouseleave(hideBox);

    function showBox(e) {
        $('.kuk-blok').fadeIn().css(({
            left: 0,
            top: 30
        }));
    }

    function hideBox() {
        $('.kuk-blok').fadeOut();
    }

    $(".kuk-blok").hover(function () {
        $(this).css('display:block');
    }, function () {
        $(this).css('display:none');
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not how jQuery's `.css` method works.  http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the "staying open" part, I use a mixture of hover() and delay().

When the mouse leaves elementX, delay the hiding of elementY.
This provides enough time to move the mouse to elementY before hiding it.
When the mouse enters elementY, its hiding animation is cancelled and it remains visible.
When the mouse leaves elementY, it hides itself.

```
$('#elementX').hover(
  function() { $('#elementY').stop(true,true).fadeIn('fast'); },
  function() { $('#elementY').stop(true,true).delay(350).fadeOut('fast'); }
);

$('#elementY').hover(
  function() { $(this).stop(true,true).show(0); },
  function() { $(this).stop(true,true).delay(150).fadeOut('fast'); }
);
```

Here's a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TUDbj/).

Comment: This solves my issue. The delay thing was the problem apparently. I use jquery 1.3.2 so I had to use something like .animate({top: 30},350) instead of delay. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the actual HTML the script relates to the most obvious issue seems to be the use of the [**css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

The `css()` method takes 2 arguments to set a value:

```
$(".kuk-blok").hover(function () {
    //$(this).css('display:block');
    $(this).css('display', 'block');
}, function () {
    //$(this).css('display:none');
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Or you can use `show()` and `hide()` if you want too:

```
$(".kuk-blok").hover(function () {
    //$(this).css('display:block');
    $(this).show();
}, function () {
    //$(this).css('display:none');
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: @user1031742: Please feel free to post the relevant HTML though in your question if you still got issues and I can revise any code to be more specific to your required scenario.